# How to stop searchView to getting focus automatically after orientation change

Tags: android, searchview, android-orientation

I have inflated searchItem as menuItem in the toolbar, my problem whenever orientation changes and if my searchView is in expanded mode then automatically its getting focus even though before orientation focus in on another view.

How can I prevent searchView from getting focus automatically?

**Before Orientation Change:**

[image]

**After orientation change:**

[image: Before orientation change]

Comment: Can you share a simple project with that behavior at github? I cannot reproduce that on my side.

Comment: Thanks @azizbekian for a hint, editText is present in recyclerView, the first item of recyclerView

Comment: Nevertheless, if you still couldn't come up with a solution, I'll look through the code if you share the project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a dummy view above your recyclerView then after rotation automatically, first focus will taken by that view so search view won't takes focus, try like this

Comment: I have added to the parent layout `android:focusable="true"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` to make it work :)

Answer (score 2):

Android will try to find the first focus-able view in your view hierarchy and focus on it. To avoid this you can add a dummy view (e.g. using a LinearLayout with 0 height and width) to steal the first focus.

```
<LinearLayout
android:focusable="true" 
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:layout_width="0px" 
android:layout_height="0px"/>
```

Comment: can you share the layout xml?

Comment: https://github.com/surendar4/ForSharingFiles/blob/master/SearchViewFocus_issue.xml